# Crystal Reports Integrated Authentication issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm stuck. I have few crystal reports in C# windows form application that feed from local SQL 2008. They all work in debug and runtime on my computer, where I wrote the app. However, CR's fail to authenticate when run from a different computer. All reports use integrated authentication and I checked properties values in Database Expert and they look correct. The app was written in VS2012 to NET Framework 4. Could the issue be related to me using single template to develop each final report?
All other items seem to be set up properly. Users have rights to access SQL and all users and computers in questions are valid members of the domain and in fact access db without problems in other applications.Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "However, CR's fail to authenticate when run from a different computer." I dont quiet get it? do they fail to load? throw exception? give error? ask for username password? please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

The issue originates from the access provider. In Set Database location look up properties of database connection. Under provider it lists how it accesses data. In my case it was SQLNCLI11. The client that was present on all workstations was older SQLOLEDB. Once changed follow the steps on each and every subreport too and remember to re-import. If you add new tables verify that they are added through correct provider - if not - correct manually.